# Why does super().__init__ () behave differently from super().override() in the Derived class in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm wondering how come the **self.name** is 'abc' when the super().__init__('abc') gets called, but it becomes 'Nicky' when super().override() is called?

Is it because the Derived instance hasn't been created yet during the time super().__init__('abc') is called so the Base class's properties are used instead?

```
class Base():
    def __init__(self, name):        
        self.name = name
        self.base = 'base class'
        print('Base', self.name)
        
    def override(self):
        print('Base-override', self.name) 

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        super().__init__('abc')
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def override(self):
        super().override() 

d = Derived('Nicky', 20)  # Base abc
d.override() # Base-override Nicky
```

Comment: because you set it to nicky after the call to super has done and finishes up the initialization in the derived class

Comment: Look at the order of execution. You call `super.__init__` with 'abc' which will print out `"Base abc"` then you re-set the value to `"Nicky"` so any further accesses to `self.name` will result in `"Nicky"`

Comment: Also to clarify, the `self.name` you have in both classes will point to the same value - they are not two different attributes

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaNixon, after id(self.name) in both classes, I realized they're pointing to the same object

Comment: Python doesn't have separate instance attributes for the parent and the class like C++, which is why multiple inheritance is much less problematic in Python than in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can understand it better if you add more prints

```
class Base():
    def __init__(self, name):      
        print('Base1', self.__dict__)  
        self.name = name
        self.base = 'base class'
        print('Base2', self.name, self.__dict__)
        
    def override(self):
        print('Base-override', self.name) 

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        print('Derived1', self.__dict__)
        super().__init__('abc')
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        print('Derived2', self.name, self.__dict__)

    def override(self):
        super().override() 

d = Derived('Nicky', 20)  # Base abc
d.override() # Base-override Nicky
```

Output

```
Derived1 {}
Base1 {}
Base2 abc {'name': 'abc', 'base': 'base class'}
Derived2 Nicky {'name': 'Nicky', 'base': 'base class', 'age': 20}
Base-override Nicky
```

There are no different versions for the attribute `name` of your object `d`, both refers to the same value, don't confuse yourself that `name` is different between the parent and child class, after all, it's just the same object, regardless of the class hierarchies.

It's just a matter of what you set last at a point in time. Here, when you called `super().__init__('abc')`, you haven't initialized the name "Nicky" in your `Derived.__init__()`, thus you saw the value of "abc" first.

Comment: Your answer is so precise, I tried id(self.name) in Base and Derived, they are pointing to the same object. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with execution order and how you use the parameters. A class is a collection of data, and has some functions to work on that data. You can use `super()` to call an implementation explicitly from the parent class.

There is nothing special about `__init__` as a method or `name` as an attribute. Your calling sequence is as follows:

1. `Derived('Nicky', 20)` creates a new empty object using `object.__new__`, then calls `Derived.__init__(obj, 'Nicky', 20)`. Remember that the attribute dictionary is empty at this point.
2. `Derived.__init__(obj, 'Nicky', 20)` starts out by calling `Base.__init__(obj, 'abc')` via `super()`.
3. `Base.__init__(obj, 'abc')` sets `obj.name` to `'abc'` and `obj.base` to `'base class'`. It then returns with those two attributes set in the dictionary. This is where the first `print` happens.
4. `Derived.__init__(obj, 'Nicky', 20)` then runs along and sets `obj.name` to `'Nicky'`, and `obj.age` to `20`. It then returns. The key point is that `obj.name` is the same attribute as what `Base.__init__` was working on: different methods, same data.
5. `Derived('Nicky', 20)` returns the newly created and initialized object, which you assign to the name `d`.
6. When you call `d.override`, or any other method, it has access to `d.__dict__` as the previous method left it.

Aside from the lesson on how instance data is stored and passed around, this is a lesson on how to design your initializers. Usually, you call `super` exactly to avoid doing unnecessary work in the derived class. In `__init__`, that means letting the base class handle name information. It also means that `override` as currently implemented shouldn't exist: the base implementation will be called on the derived instance anyway, and if that's all you're doing, you don't actually need to override it:

```
class Base():
    def __init__(self, name):        
        self.name = name
        self.base = 'base class'
        print('Base', type(self), self.name)
        
    def override(self):
        print('Base-override', type(self), self.name) 

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.age = age
```

I've added `type(self)` to your printouts so you can see that it's an instance of `Derived` that `Base` methods are called on when you instantiate `Derived`.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing mysterious here.

You are creating the base class with `name = 'abc`' but then overriding `sef.name` with 'Nicky'.

It is clear from this code:

```
    super().__init__('abc')
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
```

That in order for `self.name = name` to be executed, the expression `super().__init__('abc')` has to be completed.